# Is there a module in Python that does something like "sqldf" for R?

Tags: python, sql, r, dataframe

List comprehensions are very good. But some kind of "... Join ..." would be very useful. Thanks.
So for example. I have a Set A= {1,0}, a list B = [[1,1],[2,3]]. I would like to find all rows in B where the second colomu is one of the values in A.  Or some thing more general, I have 2 CSV files. I want to find out all the rows where  the values of some colonm from the two files match. Just like some kind of 'join' of two files. One of the files is GB size. 
[sqldf is *"SQL select on R data frames."*](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/)

Comment: You would get more/better answers if you have a brief summary of what `sqldf` does for the non-R users. Exactly what parts of its functionality do you want?

Comment: Agreed... Also, some code or at least some pseudo code to explain what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You can use pandasql, which allows for SQL style querying of pandas DataFrames. It's very similar to sqldf.

https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/

(full disclaimer, I wrote it)

EDIT: blog post documenting some of the features found here:
http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandasql-sql-for-pandas-dataframes.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm unaware of a library doing what you ask (but I only glanced at the `sqldf` documentation), however nothing of what you asked really requires a library, they are one-liners in python (and you could of course abstract the functionality creating a function rather than a simple list comprehension...)

> Set A= {1,0}, a list B = [[1,1],[2,3]]. I would like to find all rows in B where the second column is one of the values in A.

```
>>> a = set([1, 0])
>>> b = [[1,1],[2,3]]
>>> [l for l in b if l[1] in a]
[[1, 1]]
```

> I have 2 CSV files. I want to find out all the rows where the values of some column from the two files match.

```
>>> f1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> f2 = [[0, 2, 8], [7, 7, 7]]
>>> [tuple_ for tuple_ in zip(f1, f2) if tuple_[0][1] == tuple_[1][1]]
[([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 8])]
```

---

**EDIT:** If memory usage is a problem you should use generators instead of lists. For example:

```
>>> zip(f1, f2)
[([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 8]), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 7])]
```

but using generators:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> gen = it.izip(f1, f2)
>>> gen
<itertools.izip object at 0x1f24ab8>
>>> next(gen)
([1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 8])
>>> next(gen)
([4, 5, 6], [7, 7, 7])
```

And for the data source:

```
>>> [line for line in f1]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

translate as generator as:

```
>>> gen = (line for line in f1)
>>> gen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1f159b0>
>>> next(gen)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> next(gen)
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks @mac. You are right, list comprehension is similarly powerful as SQL, if you are not dealing with the  big files that can not be read in memory once. I Will be very happy if I do the same with big CSV files.

Comment: @gstar2002 - There is nothing preventing you to use this syntax with generators instead of lists. See edits.

Comment: thanks, it works for izip. But for things like ([l1,l2] for l1 in f1 for l2 in f2), it doesn't work. I only get the first line of f1 combined with all lines from f2. But I would like to have all combinations.

Comment: @gstar2002 - The answer to your problem is `it.product(f1, f2)`... **However** you should really read the documentation, try stuff and  learn Python. :) SO is not a "teach me" site, it is a "I'm stuck and I don't know where to look for the solution" site. You got your answer already: look into generators and the `itertools` library, now study those, try all the different functions, experiment... look at example code... If/when you get stuck with something after having tried all that you could think of, post a new question and we'll be here for you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you can do the functionality of sqldf you need the functionality of 'df', ie dataframes. Python has a cuddly version: pandas:

http://pandas.sourceforge.net/

Perhaps the section on joining and merging will help:

http://pandas.sourceforge.net/merging.html

I recommend you start with something smaller than your gigabyte files though!

Answer (score 1):

There is a package available now which does exactly this! Check the link below:

pysqldf => https://pypi.org/project/pysqldf/

This package will allow you to query pandas dataframe using SQL just like `sqldf`did in `R`